# У меня есть бот тех поддержки, как сделать, чтобы после моего ответа на сообщение пользователя была инлайн кнопка "Продолжить общение с ТП"?

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Как и спрашивал, мне нужно чтобы после моего ответа (ответа тех. поддержки на сообщение пользователя), у пользователя появлялась инлайн кнопка "Продолжить общение с тех. поддержкой", как это сделать?

Код:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == ' Поддержка')                              # Техподдержка
def support(message):
    appeal_tp = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    new_appeal_tp = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Обращение в тех поддержку')
    
    appeal_tp.add(new_appeal_tp)
    #bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://clck.ru/35BY47')
    #bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Если у Вас возникли вопросы или проблемы, Вы всегда можете обратиться к @clazy13", parse_mode='Markdown')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Если вы столкнулись с какой либо проблемой, напишите об этом в тех поддержку', reply_markup=appeal_tp)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, question_tp)

def question_tp(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Напишите ваше обращение к тех. поддержке:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, end_appeal)
    
def end_appeal(message):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('tp.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tp(
        digits INTEGER,
        text VARCHAR(100)
    )''')

    connect.commit()

    people_id = message.chat.id
    user_text = message.text
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tp (digits, text) VALUES(?, ?);', (people_id, user_text))

    connect.commit()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Ваше обращение принято в обработку, ожидайте ответа тех. поддержки!')
    bot.forward_message('-1001930697850', message.chat.id, message.message_id)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['answer'])
def answer_user_question(message):
    tp_need_id_user = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введите айди пользователя:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(tp_need_id_user, answer_user_text)

def answer_user_text(message):
    id_user_answer_end = message.text
    text_user_answer = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введите ответ пользователю')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(text_user_answer, answer_user_end, id_user_answer_end)

def answer_user_end(message, id_user_bot):
    bot.send_message(id_user_bot, text=f'''Новое сообщение по вашему обращению: {message.text}''')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, next_appeal_with_tp)
    
def next_appeal_with_tp(message):
    if message.text == 'next_text_user':
        next_appeal = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        next_text = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Продолжить общение с тех поддержкой', callback_data='next_text_user')
        back_menu = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Вернуться в меню', callback_data='back_menu_next_tp')
        next_appeal.add(next_text)
        next_appeal.add(back_menu)
        connect = sqlite3.connect('tp.db')
        cursor = connect.cursor()

        people_id = message.chat.id
        user_text = message.text
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tp (digits, text) VALUES(?, ?);', (people_id, user_text + '2 обращение'))
        connect.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.message.chat.id, text=f'''Отправка ответа по обращению 

    Введите сообщение или прикрепите изображение, дополненное текстом:''')
```

Comment: Отформатируйте свой вопрос, пожалуйста.